# Android setup with Eclipse plugin : Unable to find "support" folder inside "C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\extras\android"

Tags: android, eclipse

I am a beginner to Android. I have installed android sdk and the "Android support repository" is shown as "installed" by the [SDK Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sfq3g.png)

But I am unable to see the "support" folder inside "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\extras\android". the only folder available within this location is "m2repository". So I am not sure how I can include android-support jar in eclipse. Without this jar, the project compiles with multiple errors.

Many forums suggest I should install "Android Support Library" from SDK Manager, but this is not listed for me.

Can anyone please help me out here?

Comment: If you're an android beginner, then I strongly suggest you to don't start learning using the deprecated and non updated Eclipse IDE, but [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) instead. With Android Studio you ever won't have this kind of troubles.

Comment: Will try with that, thank-you